# Can I hex edit a file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, binaryfiles

I want to edit a binary file, but I don't want to use another tool other than Visual Studio because it's a pain to switch back and forth.

Is there perhaps an add-in or some built in functionality that can do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62268866/6309 with VSCode 1.46 (May 2020)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

1. Menu *File* → *Open* → *File*
2. Select the file to be opened
3. On the open file dialog at the bottom there is a down arrow on the "Open" button
4. Click "Open With..."
5. Click "Binary Editor"
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Or for the keyboard geeks out there:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (paste filename)
3. <kbd>tab</kbd>
4. <kbd>tab</kbd>
5. <kbd>↓</kbd>
6. <kbd>w</kbd>
7. <kbd>b</kbd>
8. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Loved the keyboard geeks part!

Comment: +1 for the answer, but now for a rant (not against Kevin's answer, but against these controls)... Those buttons-with-options that MS uses sometimes in file open dialogs (does this control have a commonly used name?) seem like a neat idea, but from a usability perspective they don't work well. At least for me. While there's the little down-arrow indicator on the button, it still strikes me as non-discoverable since that indicator is effectively invisible. I never notice them, and from the questions I've seen where the answer is 'use that little down arrow on the button', I'm not the only one.

Comment: it seems it is not available in Express edition (or maybe there is something to active in settings/options which is not enabled by default ?).

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb4x6esf.aspx 
The Binary Editor is not available in Express editions.

Comment: looks like somebody forgot to put it in VS2015 Preview too :-(
or maybe I just forgot to install it

Comment: The "Binary Editor" option isn't showing up for me in VS2017 Pro.

Comment: For anyone who arrived here looking for the Binary Editor in VS2017, see the answer from @jordanbtucker.

Comment: If the Binary Editor refuses to open the file then make sure the file is not open in another application.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724591/164430), with Visual Studio 2017 you need to have the **Visual Studio C++ Core Features** component installed.

[Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15286/cant-find-binary-editor.html)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it is to rename your file to .bin and drag it into VS editor

Answer (score 1):

1. **right click** the file in Solution Explorer,
2. select 'Open With...'
3. select 'Binary Editor'

Let's enjoy the hex world :)

[image]