# How to programmatically do a "screen recording" of an AVI file

Tags: encode, avi, wmv, screen-recording

I have an AVI file(s) with a date time banner incrementing by the second as the video plays. 
The time banner is put on the AVI by a proprietary codec; its not in the files metadata, nor is there anything obvious in the avi file that looks like a start time when viewed through a [binary editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724586/can-i-hex-edit-a-file-in-visual-studio).

Ideally I would like to stitch the file(s) together, do some overlay, encode them to wmv format and stream through Windows Media Services. However when I encode (using expression encoder) to wmv I lose the date time banner.

Is there a API or tool available where I can programmatically "screen record" the video date time prior (or during) encoding?