# Visual Studio Hexadecimal Display Uppercase

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I work directly with binaries files, doing a lot of reverse engineering and inserting security patches to bypass some things.

Anyways this means I'm constantly starring at hexadecimal, and I have my hexadecimal display enabled in Visual Studio, but the one thing that my mind has a hard time with is all other hex editors put their alpha-numeric numbers (0xA-0xF) in uppercase, Visual Studio is lower case.  I've spent some time looking over all the options and references but couldn't find anything.  Anyone know of an option to change this to uppercase?

I'm talking the debugging hexadecimal display for example I want this to be in uppercase:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Using the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1724586/1896169), I see the alpha chars in uppercase

Comment: Sorry I was misleading with my original statement.  I'm not using Visual Studio to edit binary files, I'm creating patching scripts in C#.  So I'm looking to change the debugging display.  Updated original post with image.

Comment: Ahh, not the editor, but the debugger