# How to count lines including the ending new lines?

Tags: c++11

I have been searching online for a long time and there is no correct answer as far as I can find. Now the most common answer looks like below:

```
int main() { 
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("textexample.txt");

    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        ++number_of_lines;
    std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
    return 0;
}
```

If the `textexample.txt` file actually has two empty lines at the end, this program will only count one of them, I'm guessing the first one. Such as below:

```
1
2
3

4
5
6
```

The above 6 numbers and 3 empty lines are 9 lines in total, but the program above will return 8.

I don't know why, but it seems `std::getline()` only loops 8 times.

Comment: I just noticed that if I have this text with two newlines at the end then vim shows 8 lines, but visual studio shows 9. To be clear; I didn't include the line shown as `end`. [Here it is in hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1dGT.png).

Comment: But I'm using visual studio and it actually shows 8!

Comment: [Here it is in Visual Studio's editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fBNd.png).
[Here it is in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEu3n.png).

Comment: What do you have in hex? Use the [open with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724586/can-i-hex-edit-a-file-in-visual-studio) menu option to view in hex.

Comment: So is there other way to write this code so that it always work?

Comment: I don't know what hex is

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/jXFMyr

Comment: Well then I don't know what's the issue. It really returns 8 on my visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

The file in your example has 10 lines, of which 3 are empty. And if I run your code (with the missing includes...) it tells me there are 10 lines. So either you're running different code, or you're mis-quoting the file. Or you C++ standard library is broken somehow...

If I remove the line with "end", I get 9, not 8, lines.

Comment: As I said, ignore that "end" in the end. I only add that so that the two new lines in the end would be formatted. Don't paste that into your txt file...

Comment: @FluffySkye: Doesn't matter, the count is still right.

Comment: @FluffySkye I fixed your formatting and removed the `end`